# How to implement skim engine, client-side templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was recommended to use skim in my project. I can't implement it right.
It is said to only add skim gem to GEMFILE. I've done that, made a template task.jst.skim, but than when Im trying to render it i get ReferenceError: JST is not defined. so what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

adding `//= require_tree ../templates` in application.js solved the problem